# Adding EC2 Cassandra Nodes to my already running premise Apache Cassandra Cluster

Tags: amazon-ec2, cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-3.0, cassandra-2.1

Here is my use case:
  I have a single DC Cassandra cluster(3 nodes) with RF 2. This Cluster is running on my on-premises DC. Here is my question, I am hoping to add 3 EC2 nodes into this cluster and then change the RF to say 4, also add one of the ec2 nodes as a seed after all 3 nodes fully join the cluster.

Do I need to change the Snitch on the EC2 nodes? or can I just add each nodes?

If you have implemented this use case, I will appreciate a clean clear step and what gotcha I should look out for?

Comment: when you say RF:4 dont you mean DC-on-premise:2 and DC-aws:2 ? What snitch do you already have?

Comment: @markc. my current snitch is SimpleSnitch. which is what I have running on my on-premise Cassandra cluster. As for RF this is what I have CREATE KEYSPACE ***  WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': 2} so, I am hoping after all the ec2 nodes are added, I can then change it to CREATE KEYSPACE ****  WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': 4}

Let me know if my idea makes sense. feel free to ping me any documentation that you have. Thanks

Comment: ok so `SimpleSnitch` (which is the default) is going to cause you a problem here. Its probably best to use the `GossipingPropertyFileSnitch` instead

Comment: One you have switched out the snitch then change the KS replication to use `NetworkTopologyStrategy`

Answer (score 1):

You can add 3 EC2 nodes to your on-prem cluster, but... you will have to set up 2 data centers to do it with 3 nodes in each DC, 2 DCs in your cluster. You won't be able to use SimpleSnitch; as markc commented, your best bet is [GossipingPropertyFileSnitch](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/architecture/archsnitchGossipPF.html). Although you didn't mention it,  [SimpleStrategy](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsChangeKSStrategy.html) is not recommended for production and you'll need to change it to NetworkTopologyStrategy. Markc should post his comments as the answer here :)